# Is the “leaking arguments” a lie?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arguments

In Javascript, [there is a point](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments) that "arguments leaking" can affect optimization. For example:

```
function leakingArguments() {
    var a = arguments;
    return function() {
        return a;
    };
}
```

`Arguments leaking` which is a function arguments be used outside that function. In this case, compiler may not optimize that code.

So I built a [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/argument-leaking-without-other-effect), their performance is equalit. It seems passing the arguments out of function wouldn't affect the results execution time.

```
let MAX_LENGTH = 1000

let arr = Array.from({length: MAX_LENGTH}, (v, i) => i)

let withoutArguments = function() {
  let cloneArgs = Array.apply(null, arguments)

  return function() {
    cloneArgs[0] = 1
    return
  }
}

let argumentsFn = function() {
  let args = arguments
  let cloneArgs = Array.apply(null, arguments)

  return function() {
    args[0] = 1
    return
  }
}

withoutArguments(...arr)
argumentsFn(...arr)
```

Is there a real existing about "arguments leaking"?

Comment: Your question seems kind of generic and probably calls for a lot of opinion.  Can you focus it on one or two specific code cases and show the code for those in the question so just reading the question, we can see what cases you're asking about?  Here at stackoverflow, we aren't supposed to have to go fishing around in links you provide just to understand what exact cases the core question is about.  This is for a variety of reasons, the biggest of which is that external links have a habit of disappearing or changing over time rendering the question unclear to those who come by in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, I am trying to move closer to this standard.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to question your performance testcase because:

(1) You only call these functions once, it is unlikely that the engine JIT compiles them, and that's the place were optimizations really matter.

(2) You never call the function returned, so you never actually modify `arguments`.

(3) The main problem with `arguments` is that the values have to be reflected live into the closured variables, so this testcase would be much better:

```
function urgh(a) {
 const leak = arguments;
 return function() {
   leak.a = 1;
   console.log(a);
 };
}
```